# Почему не работает event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Почему не работает event.preventDefault();?

Идея в вот что при выборе изображения, они должны автоматический загружаться на сервер при помощи Ajax

```js
$(document).on('change', '#file_input', function() {

  var form = document.getElementById('file_upload');

  form.submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    NProgress.start();

    $.ajax({
      type: $(this).attr('method'),
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data: new FormData(this),
      statusCode: {
        404: function() {
          alert("Страница не найдена.");
        }
      },
      success: function(result) {

        console.log(result.src);

        if (result.notify) {
          $('#notify').append('<div class="notify_block">' + result.notify + '</div>');
          setTimeout(function() {
            hideNotify();
          }, 5000);
        }
        NProgress.done();
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
        // console.log(xhr.responseText);
        NProgress.done();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="file_preview"></div>

<div class="input_block">
  <form action="{{route('files.upload', $company->id)}}" method="POST" id="file_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="company_id" value="{{$company->id}}">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple id="file_input">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что form.submit() - это метод отправляющий форму через JS. А вам нужно событие form.onsubmit

Answer (score 1):

В коде смешан jQuery и чистый JS. Форма возвращается через API браузера, а используется как объект jQuery.

Это дело можно починить как-то так:

```js
var form = $('#file_upload');

form.submit(function(event) {
  ...
})
```